# Can I create actions based on HTML elements to show and hide divs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Novice* -
I am building a page in a TinyMCE wysiwyg and want to be able to show and hide divs when a link/button is clicked. The way things are structured, it appears I can't add javascript into the html section, so I am identifying the links with javascript.

From examples I was able to create the following code, which toggles a single div when clicking on any button marked with the toggleLink class. Is there a good way to target individual elements to show 1 div and hide the rest? I think getElementById might be heading in the right direction, but I am not sure how to apply the eventListeners individually

```js
var togg = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleLink");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < togg.length; i++) {
  togg[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var openDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
    if (openDiv.style.display === "none"){
      openDiv.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      openDiv.style.display = "none";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.demoLinks {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px; 
    width: 15%; 
    font-size: 14pt; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #3156f3; 
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px; 
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
    float: left; 
    position: sticky; top: 100px;
}

.demoLinks p {
    margin-bottom: 2px; 
    padding-left: 15px; 
    color: #ffffff;
}

.demoLinks p a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.toggleLink {
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor:pointer;
}


.demoVideos {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 75%; 
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px; 
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
    float: right;"
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="demoLinks">
<p style="margin-bottom: 8px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;">Products:</p>
<p><a class="toggleLink">This Link</a></p>
<p><a class="toggleLink"> ThatLink</a></p>
</div>
<div class="demoVideos">
<div id="myDIV1" style="display: block;">
<p style="margin-bottom: 0.25em;"><span style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #2b28bc; margin-bottom: 0.5em;"><strong><span style="font-size: 24pt;">Product Demo 1</span></strong></span></p>
<div style="height:585px; width:1034px; background-color:#333333;"></div>
</div>
<div id="myDIV2" style="display: none;">
<p style="margin-bottom: 0.25em;"><span style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color: #2b28bc; margin-bottom: 0.5em;"><strong><span style="font-size: 24pt;">Product Demo 2</span></strong></span></p>
<div style="height:585px; width:1034px; background-color:#333333;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can correlate your links with your targets using a suffix on the 'id' property.  So, for instance, you can give your first link an id of 'link1', which you can then relate to 'myDIV1' by replacing the text 'link' with 'myDIV'.  And the same logic then for all link-div associations.

Once you have that, you should know that the function you pass to an event listener accepts a parameter which is the event that ultimately calls it.  You can use this to get the id of the link that was clicked (`e.target.id`);

With that you can show the target div you're interested in, and hide the rest.

Below is a very simplified version of your code, along with my recommended logic.  I should let you know that `querySelectorAll` has similar purposes to `getElement(s)By...`, but lets you select using css selectors.  Also, the syntax 'test ? trueResult : falseResult' can be replaced by an if/then statement if you desire.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.toggleLink');
var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demoVideos > div');

for (var l = 0; l < links.length; l++) {
  links[l].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  
    var linkDivId = e.target.id;
    var targetDivId = linkDivId.replace('link', 'myDIV');

    for (var d = 0; d < demos.length; d++) 
        demos[d].style.display = demos[d].id == targetDivId ? 'block' : 'none';
    
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="demoLinks">
   <a id='link1' class="toggleLink">Demo 1 Link</a><br/>
   <a id='link2' class="toggleLink">Demo 2 Link</a>
</div>

<br/>
<div class="demoVideos">
   <div id="myDIV1" style="display: none;">
       Product Demo 1
   </div>
   <div id="myDIV2" style="display: none;">
        Product Demo 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, forgive me a bit I took some liberties with your markup and CSS to make it easier for me to visualize the task at hand - toggle of visibility.

Rather than use an element id, I would suggest a class but here, I put in a `data-linktarget` on each of the links so you can simply put a selector in there and use either an id, class or whatever you choose which should give your task some flexibility.

Next, I used a `hidden` class to toggle the visibility of the target - this can be done several ways but I used this to help make intent clear.  I also toggle the "active" class but did not do anything with it other than facilities what you had started.

Rather than a complex set of event handlers on multiple id's, I used a class to target the `toggleLink` class.

I made the code somewhat simple but enough to illustrate what it is doing.

```js
function handleEvent(event) {
  let videos = document.querySelector(".demo-videos");
  let hideMe = videos.querySelectorAll(".demo-thing:not(.hidden)");
  hideMe.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.toggle("hidden", true);
    el.classList.toggle("active", false);
  });
  let vSelected = videos.querySelector(this.dataset.linktarget);
  vSelected.classList.toggle("hidden", false);
  vSelected.classList.toggle("active", true);
}

Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByClassName("toggleLink"), function(testElement) {
  testElement.addEventListener("click", handleEvent);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.demo-container {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.demoLinks {
  height: 200px;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 14pt;
  background-color: #3156f3;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.demo-links-title-text {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #FFFF00;
}

.demoLinks .demo-link {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.toggleLink {
  color: #FFFF88;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.demo-videos {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  float: right;
}

.demo-videos .header-part {
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.demo-videos .header-part .header-part-text {
  color: #2b28bc;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* put back <strong> tags if desired instead */
}

.demo-videos .block-part {
  height: 585px;
  width: 1034px;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demoLinks">
    <p class="demo-links-title-text">Products:</p>
    <p class="demo-link"><a class="toggleLink" data-linktarget="#myDIV1" href="#">This Link</a></p>
    <p class="demo-link"><a class="toggleLink" data-linktarget=".demo-thing:nth-child(2)" href="#">ThatLink</a></p>
    <p class="demo-link"><a class="toggleLink" data-linktarget=".demo-thing:nth-child(3)" href="#">That new Link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="demo-videos">
    <div id="myDIV1" class="demo-thing active">
      <p class="header-part"><span class="header-part-text"><span>Product Demo 1</span></span>
      </p>
      <div class="block-part">I am first</div>
    </div>
    <div id="myDIV2" class="demo-thing hidden">
      <p class="header-part"><span class="header-part-text"><span>Product Demo 2</span></span>
      </p>
      <div class="block-part">Happy Day</div>
    </div>
    <div id="another-id" class="demo-thing hidden">
      <p class="header-part"><span class="header-part-text"><span>Product Demo New</span></span>
      </p>
      <div class="block-part">Wonderful news</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```